# Tabs and swipe views error in tools:listitem

Tags: android, listview, tabs, swipe

I have implemented a tabs and swipe method inside my application, Here's [a link](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tabs-and-swipe-views/?lang=en)! (this is the nice tutorial)
inside my application in the first TAB I have a ListView and the row are defined in other xml.

**this is tab1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LinearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ccffcc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">           
<!--        tools:listitem="@layout/row"> -->

        </ListView>     
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the **row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_prodotto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Prodotto"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" />

     <View
         android:id="@+id/viewLine"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:layout_below="@id/tv_prodotto"
         android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
         android:background="#666666" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_qta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_prodotto"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="Quantita"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the compiler give me an error in the *tools:listitem*

This is the error: ***Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix***
before implement the Tabs and swipe method (in a normal application) the ***tools:listitem="@layout/row"*** run correctly without compiler error!
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I will save you all the trouble.

I hope you're using the eclipse.

When you create new android project in Eclipse, they give you option if you want to implement tab swipe (many other options too).

While creating the new project, on very last window. They give you option for "Navigation Type". This is where you choose if you want to implement tab with swipe feature. To implement tab with swipe, your minimum API has to be 11. [image: Here is the last window while creating the new android project.]

Let me know how it goes, if you have any other question feel free to ask.

Hope this help you out.

Comment: thanks, for your answer, but my application run correctly with in tabs mode, the problem is only in my ListView. 
Before modify the application in tabs mode, the application show me the ListView in correct mode, after modify the application , the same ListView layout give me the error above:
**Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix**